# React Dropzone accept="image/jpeg" is blocking other related function when it executes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js

I am using `Dropzone` from `react-dropzone` and want to upload only `JPED` files.
When I use `accept="image/jpeg"` on file opening dialog only `JPEG` files appearing but it is blocking other relating function incide `onDrop`
If user uploads other format files like `png, pdf` it should alert error message:

```
const ALLOWED_FORMAT = 'image/jpeg'
```

```
       if (!ALLOWED_FORMAT.includes(acceptedFiles[i].type)) {
          alert("Onlu JPEG files accepted")

          break;
        }
```

if I remove `accept="image/jpeg"` from `Dropzone` this function works as expected but I need to run both. If user uploads other formats this alter function should execute and alert error message! Where should I change or what should I add/remove?